# How to detect if a mobile device is emulated by Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, android, mobile

Is there a way to distinguish a real mobile device from a device emulated by Google Chrome?
Please note that Google Chrome can emulate Useragent, touchscreen, screen resolution and accelerometer.
I need to know some features which cannot be emulated but can be detected by javascript.

Comment: Why would you want something like this? (Just of curiosity)

Comment: which feature do you want to access that can not be emulated?

Comment: did you check "window.navigator" property.

Comment: Is there a particular device you are looking to differentiate (e.g. iPhone)? The approach will be different for different devices

Comment: `navigator.vendor` always return `Google Inc.` even emulate iPhone.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem this is useful when making hybrid apps (supporting browser/web app and mobile device app), sometimes you want to load libraries/scripts based on whether in browser or smart device app. Example: cordova.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to check for navigator.plugins.length.
Mobile browsers have no plugins, so navigator.plugins.length is equal to 0;
Desktop browsers ordinary have plugins, so we can distinguish browsers by length of plugins array.

Comment: I'd say, that we can also use navigator.platform property.

Comment: This no longer works. `navigator.plugins.length === 0` on Chrome when it's emulating iOS.

Comment: var isSmartDevice =
    /* mobile if android or iOS and not emulated in mac or win pc (for dev) \*/
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/(android|ip(hone|ad|od))/i) && (!navigator.platform || !navigator.platform.match(/(win|mac)/i)))
    /* or if windows phone or blackberry (no dev in windows) */
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/(windows phone|iemobile|wpdesktop|blackberry)/i);

Comment: @KamilSzymański worked great for me.

Comment: The definitive way to determine this is to check for `navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1` Because Chrome emulated devices will always have only 1 touchpoint (ie. your mouse cursor), while actual (modern) mobile devices will always have more than 1, and devices without touch support will always have 0. You're welcome.

Comment: @Ivan what would happen when someone using Chrome on laptop with touchscreen support?

Comment: @blackbiron I tested this: I have verified that `navigator.maxTouchPoints` is 10 on a touch screen computer when mobile emulation is *not* running, but it is 1 when mobile emulation is running. So that's good news.

Comment: thanks a lot @MarcDurdin