# How to find actual mobile device or chrome desktop mobile emulator

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, phonegap, mobile-chrome

I am using cordova and I want to execute/block some function depending on its device. How can I find the details.

**What I tried?**
I am searching lot and find a solution for it but it is not worked the link is 
[How to detect if a mobile device is emulated by Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083715/how-to-detect-if-a-mobile-device-is-emulated-by-google-chrome)

always I am getting navigator.plugins.length is getting 0

Comment: Cant you use the onDeviceReady event? you should be able to set some functions for browser or mobile device

Comment: I tried, but no use